# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Servlet

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I am writing servlet to connect with `mysql` database using `mysqlconnector` java but it is giving error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I have tried same with core `java` using the same driver it is connecting to mysql and query is also running but using servlet it is not working.

my code is for `servlet` is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;





public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String n = request.getParameter("userName");
        String p = request.getParameter("password");
        String e = request.getParameter("email");
        String c = request.getParameter("course");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phpmyadmin/saiiff","root", "");
            PreparedStatement ps =  conn
                    .prepareStatement("insert into eemeze values(?,?,?,?)");

            ps.setString(1, n);
            ps.setString(2, p);
            ps.setString(3, e);
            ps.setString(4, c);

            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0)
                out.print("You are successfully registered...");

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }

        out.close();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think mysql library is not included...

Comment: mysql driver is there I have added using build path add external libraries..the same code is running from core java and data is also inserted but using servlet it is not working

Comment: Did you check if jdbc connector jar was included in web library? That is was the server able to access it? Are you using eclipse?

Comment: yes it is there it is working if i remove port no 3306 from connection driver manager

Answer (score -1):

1. Download the mysql jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.mysql/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar.zip
2. And Build on classpath

Comment: I already have jar but the problem is with port no. if i remove port no 3306 it is working fine

Comment: Why suggest an ancient version of the driver from an untrusted source? MySQL Connector/J 5.1.5 is from 2007, the latest version is 5.1.45 from 30 November 2017. A trusted download link would be https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ On top of that, this wouldn't even solve this specific problem.